# Spring Boot - Issue with Spring Boot Starter Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

So I am creating a new spring boot project and wanted to play around with spring-boot-starter-actuator. However I am facing issues when starting the application.

Pom Snippet:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

`<spring-boot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>`

`spring-boot`s on my classpath:
[image]

Error while starting the application:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.bindEntityManagerFactoryToRegistry(HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration.java:68)

The following method did not exist:

    io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jpa.HibernateMetrics.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)V

The method's class, io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jpa.HibernateMetrics, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/rahul/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.2/micrometer-core-1.0.2.jar!/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jpa/HibernateMetrics.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/rahul/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.2/micrometer-core-1.0.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jpa.HibernateMetrics
```

At this point the exception happens:
[image]

However there is only one constructor of `HibernateMetrics` which looks like this:

```
public HibernateMetrics(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, String entityManagerFactoryName, Iterable<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = Tags.concat(tags, "entityManagerFactory", entityManagerFactoryName);
        this.stats = hasStatisticsEnabled(entityManagerFactory) ? getStatistics(entityManagerFactory) : null;
    }
```

From the dependency analyzer, one could see that there are not multiple versions of `micrometer-core`:
[image]

I also tried with `spring-boot-starter-actuator version of 2.2.0.RELEASE` but that has the same issue.

I am not sure what am I missing here, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` on your classpath? And normally you don't need `spring-boot-starter`. And mixing versions is not a good idea

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have updated my question - added a screenshot of all the spring-boot deps. And no, I dont have `spring-boot-start-web` because it's not a web application. Also as I said, I was consistent with my versions here, the version being `2.2.0.RELEASE`. However, since actuator wasn't working, I was playing with different spring-boot versions

Comment: Also, updated the pom deps to remove the `2.2.6-RELEASE` version on `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. So all of them are using the same version now - `2.2.0.RELEASE`

Comment: You know `spring-boot-starter-actuator` creates web-endpoints so...

Comment: Looks like you have some other dependency that pulls in an older version of micrometer-core. The version should be 1.3.0 (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.2.0.RELEASE), but you're reporting 1.0.2. Try listing all dependencies (using `mvn dependency:tree`) to see which library uses the older version of micrometer-core.

Comment: well I did `mvn dependency:tree` and I just see one version of it, thats the first thing I checked. I also checked for multiple dependencies using the `dependency analyzer` plugin on intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you'll connect a spring-boot-actuator application to a JMX console.  ( "because it's not a web application")

I've used Spring Initializr based on your pom dependencies and a CommandLineRunner example. Github example:  https://github.com/thiagochagas/actuator-example

Adjusts:
I've removed the "spring-boot-starter" dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I've used a Thread.sleep(30000L) in the DemoApplication class to simplify the example.

Install and Run the Application:

```
./mvnw clean install
java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Open the jconsole:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole
```

While your application is running it should be on the jconsole.

Select your "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" to analyze:
[image]

If this message is shown, select the option "Insecure Connection":
[image]

Analysis of the running application:
[image]